# Using .JAR file within Web Application

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how to develop web applications and I am a little stuck.

I want to create a movie review application.  It has a few java class/packages which is inside a JAR file:
               moviewebapp.jar
package -      moviewebapp.movie
class -        Movie.class

package -      moviewebApp.servlet
               MovieServlet.class

And a servlet class which has methods such as doPost, doGet, getMovie, updateMovie etc.

I have added the .JAR file to my build path.

I have developed a simple page where a user can click add movie review, which opens up a form where they can input the movie name and rating.

I now want to save the users input to a datastore.  How do I use the methods within the servlet class in my javascript to deal with the post of the information about the movie?

I have tried doing imports and then trying to create a servlet object but I dont think I have the correct syntax or maybe thats not how I'm meant to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question is much too vague to be answered. And you even seem to confuse Java with JavaScript. Post your code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: You'll need to post the code that you're trying currently so that people can help you with it.

Comment: @LewisSmith I don't see any mention of war file or web-inf/lib etc and on top of it you mentioned `trying to create a servlet object `... .Did you package your code as war file and deployed it in some web server like tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Jars are libraries you should not modify its code unless untill it is last option. You can import it's classes and use methods of those classes. 
By your question it seems you are new to Java. So I suggest you should start with hello world tutorials of servers and jdbc then start developing applications. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to provide some guidance:

Easiest solution (not the best) : you have to submit your page to receive the entry from the user. Doing this you are going to lose the status of the page on the client side.

A better solution is to make a asynchronous javascript request to get the answer provided by the user for you to process on the server side.